# How to toggle checkbox selection rather than only selecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently am using this JavaScript code snippet to select 3 checkboxes at a time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $cbs = $('input:checkbox[name="select[]"]'),
       $links = $('a[name="check"]');

   $links.click(function() {
      var start = $links.index(this) * 3,
          end = start + 3;
      $cbs.slice(start,end).prop("checked",true);
   });
});
```

Currently this code only selects the checkboxes, however I was wondering if anyone knew how to modify it so that it toggles the checkbox selection on and off?

Here's an example of my current code: "[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShZNF/)" - click the 1-3, 4-6 links etc to check the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the second argument to the `prop("checked", ...)` call depend on the "checked" status of the first (or other) checkbox in the slice:

```javascript
// ...
$cbs.slice(start,end).prop("checked", !$cbs.slice(start).prop("checked"));
```

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShZNF/2/).

**[Edit]** Or to update each checkbox in the slice individually:

```javascript
// ...
$cbs.slice(start,end).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prop("checked", !$this.prop("checked"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShZNF/3/

Comment: Better solution, I didn't know .removeProp was so destructive.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $cbs.slice(start,end).each(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $(this).removeProp("checked");   
       } else {
           $(this).prop("checked",true);
       }
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShZNF/1/

Edit: Maeric's solution is better. I wasn't aware removeProp had this gotcha:

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as
>   checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property
>   completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use
>   .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: I thought that you were supposed to have `checked="checked"` if it's true and nothing if it's not, not something like `checked="false"`.

Comment: As far as I know, the presence of checked does the trick. It may be a bad habit. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_checked.asp lists 'checked' as valid - Couldn't find a better link than w3Schools =/

Comment: ["A switch is "on" when the control element's checked attribute is set."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#checkbox) While setting it to "checked" doesn't seem to do anything, it seems to me that setting it to false should still make it checked, so long as it's set.